# DataTable fixedHeader.adjust() not working properly when sidebar is toggled

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, datatable, datatables

In my page there is a sidebar and datatable, refer this fiddle -> **https://jsfiddle.net/ymqtsdwb/2/**

**Please see the fiddle in full screen.**

```
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description"
        content="Responsive sidebar template with sliding effect and dropdown menu based on bootstrap 3">
    <title>Sidebar template</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.13.4/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/fixedheader/3.3.2/css/fixedHeader.dataTables.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"
        integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.6/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
        id="bootstrap-css">
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
   
</head>

<body>
    <div class="page-wrapper chiller-theme toggled">
        <a id="show-sidebar" class="btn btn-sm btn-dark" href="#">
            <i class="fas fa-bars"></i>
        </a>
        <nav id="sidebar" class="sidebar-wrapper">
            <div class="sidebar-content">
                <div class="sidebar-brand">
                    <a href="#">pro sidebar</a>
                    <div id="close-sidebar">
                        <i class="fas fa-times"></i>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="sidebar-header">
                    <div class="user-pic">
                        <img class="img-responsive img-rounded"
                            src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/azouaoui-med/pro-sidebar-template/gh-pages/src/img/user.jpg"
                            alt="User picture">
                    </div>
                    <div class="user-info">
                        <span class="user-name">Jhon
                            <strong>Smith</strong>
                        </span>
                        <span class="user-role">Administrator</span>
                        <span class="user-status">
                            <i class="fa fa-circle"></i>
                            <span>Online</span>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- sidebar-header  -->
                <div class="sidebar-search">
                    <div>
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control search-menu" placeholder="Search...">
                            <div class="input-group-append">
                                <span class="input-group-text">
                                    <i class="fa fa-search" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                                </span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- sidebar-search  -->
                <div class="sidebar-menu">
                    <ul>
                        <li class="header-menu">
                            <span>General</span>
                        </li>
                        <li class="sidebar-dropdown">
                            <a href="#">
                                <i class="fa fa-tachometer-alt"></i>
                                <span>Dashboard</span>
                                <span class="badge badge-pill badge-warning">New</span>
                            </a>
                            <div class="sidebar-submenu">
                                <ul>
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="#">Dashboard 1
                                            <span class="badge badge-pill badge-success">Pro</span>
                                        </a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="#">Dashboard 2</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="#">Dashboard 3</a>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li class="sidebar-dropdown">
                            <a href="#">
                                <i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i>
                                <span>E-commerce</span>
                                <span class="badge badge-pill badge-danger">3</span>
                            </a>
                            <div class="sidebar-submenu">
                                <ul>
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="#">Products

                                        </a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="#">Orders</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="#">Credit cart</a>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li class="sidebar-dropdown">
                            <a href="#">
                                <i class="far fa-gem"></i>
                                <span>Components</span>
                            </a>
                            <div class="sidebar-submenu">
                                <ul>
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="#">General</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="#">Panels</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="#">Tables</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="#">Icons</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="#">Forms</a>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li class="sidebar-dropdown">
                            <a href="#">
                                <i class="fa fa-chart-line"></i>
                                <span>Charts</span>
                            </a>
                            <div class="sidebar-submenu">
                                <ul>
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="#">Pie chart</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="#">Line chart</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="#">Bar chart</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="#">Histogram</a>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li class="sidebar-dropdown">
                            <a href="#">
                                <i class="fa fa-globe"></i>
                                <span>Maps</span>
                            </a>
                            <div class="sidebar-submenu">
                                <ul>
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="#">Google maps</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="#">Open street map</a>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li class="header-menu">
                            <span>Extra</span>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">
                                <i class="fa fa-book"></i>
                                <span>Documentation</span>
                                <span class="badge badge-pill badge-primary">Beta</span>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">
                                <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>
                                <span>Calendar</span>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">
                                <i class="fa fa-folder"></i>
                                <span>Examples</span>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <!-- sidebar-menu  -->
            </div>
            <!-- sidebar-content  -->
            <div class="sidebar-footer">
                <a href="#">
                    <i class="fa fa-bell"></i>
                    <span class="badge badge-pill badge-warning notification">3</span>
                </a>
                <a href="#">
                    <i class="fa fa-envelope"></i>
                    <span class="badge badge-pill badge-success notification">7</span>
                </a>
                <a href="#">
                    <i class="fa fa-cog"></i>
                    <span class="badge-sonar"></span>
                </a>
                <a href="#">
                    <i class="fa fa-power-off"></i>
                </a>
            </div>
        </nav>
        <!-- sidebar-wrapper  -->
        <main class="page-content">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <table>
                    <table id="table" class="table table-striped table-bordered display dataTable">
                        <thead class="bg-primary" style="color:white;">
                            <tr>
                                <th><input type="checkbox" /></th>
                                <th>Name</th>
                                <th>Age</th>
                                <th>ABSC</th>
                                <th>Status</th>
                                <th>Nominee</th>
                                <th>Date</th>
                                <th>Remarks</th>
                                <th>Actions</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td><input type="checkbox" class="rowBox" name="selectCurrentRow" id="selectCurrentRow">
                                </td>
                                <td><span>Mahadev </span></td>
                                <td><span>92</span></td>
                                <td><span>Shiva</span></td>
                                <td><span>Some</span></td>
                                <td><span>Salsette</span></td>
                                <td><span >5/25/2023</span></td>
                                <td>Dummy Remark</td>
                                <td><a style="color:white;"
                                        class="btn btn-success btn-sm btn-rounded editbtn" title="Edit"><i
                                            class="mdi mdi-pencil"></i></a> <a 
                                        class="btn btn-rounded btn-secondary btn-sm viewBtn" style="color:white;"><i
                                            class="mdi mdi-eye"></i></a> <a 
                                        class="btn btn-rounded btn-danger btn-sm deleteBtn" style="color:white;"><i
                                            class="mdi mdi-delete"></i></a></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td><input type="checkbox" class="rowBox" name="selectCurrentRow" id="selectCurrentRow">
                                </td>
                                <td><span>Mahadev </span></td>
                                <td><span>92</span></td>
                                <td><span>Shiva</span></td>
                                <td><span>Some</span></td>
                                <td><span>Salsette</span></td>
                                <td><span >5/25/2023</span></td>
                                <td>Dummy Remark</td>
                                <td><a style="color:white;"
                                        class="btn btn-success btn-sm btn-rounded editbtn" title="Edit"><i
                                            class="mdi mdi-pencil"></i></a> <a 
                                        class="btn btn-rounded btn-secondary btn-sm viewBtn" style="color:white;"><i
                                            class="mdi mdi-eye"></i></a> <a 
                                        class="btn btn-rounded btn-danger btn-sm deleteBtn" style="color:white;"><i
                                            class="mdi mdi-delete"></i></a></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td><input type="checkbox" class="rowBox" name="selectCurrentRow" id="selectCurrentRow">
                                </td>
                                <td><span>Mahadev </span></td>
                                <td><span>92</span></td>
                                <td><span>Shiva</span></td>
                                <td><span>Some</span></td>
                                <td><span>Salsette</span></td>
                                <td><span >5/25/2023</span></td>
                                <td>Dummy Remark</td>
                                <td><a style="color:white;"
                                        class="btn btn-success btn-sm btn-rounded editbtn" title="Edit"><i
                                            class="mdi mdi-pencil"></i></a> <a 
                                        class="btn btn-rounded btn-secondary btn-sm viewBtn" style="color:white;"><i
                                            class="mdi mdi-eye"></i></a> <a 
                                        class="btn btn-rounded btn-danger btn-sm deleteBtn" style="color:white;"><i
                                            class="mdi mdi-delete"></i></a></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td><input type="checkbox" class="rowBox" name="selectCurrentRow" id="selectCurrentRow">
                                </td>
                                <td><span>Mahadev </span></td>
                                <td><span>92</span></td>
                                <td><span>Shiva</span></td>
                                <td><span>Some</span></td>
                                <td><span>Salsette</span></td>
                                <td><span >5/25/2023</span></td>
                                <td>Dummy Remark</td>
                                <td><a style="color:white;"
                                        class="btn btn-success btn-sm btn-rounded editbtn" title="Edit"><i
                                            class="mdi mdi-pencil"></i></a> <a 
                                        class="btn btn-rounded btn-secondary btn-sm viewBtn" style="color:white;"><i
                                            class="mdi mdi-eye"></i></a> <a 
                                        class="btn btn-rounded btn-danger btn-sm deleteBtn" style="color:white;"><i
                                            class="mdi mdi-delete"></i></a></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td><input type="checkbox" class="rowBox" name="selectCurrentRow" id="selectCurrentRow">
                                </td>
                                <td><span>Mahadev </span></td>
                                <td><span>92</span></td>
                                <td><span>Shiva</span></td>
                                <td><span>Some</span></td>
                                <td><span>Salsette</span></td>
                                <td><span >5/25/2023</span></td>
                                <td>Dummy Remark</td>
                                <td><a style="color:white;"
                                        class="btn btn-success btn-sm btn-rounded editbtn" title="Edit"><i
                                            class="mdi mdi-pencil"></i></a> <a 
                                        class="btn btn-rounded btn-secondary btn-sm viewBtn" style="color:white;"><i
                                            class="mdi mdi-eye"></i></a> <a 
                                        class="btn btn-rounded btn-danger btn-sm deleteBtn" style="color:white;"><i
                                            class="mdi mdi-delete"></i></a></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td><input type="checkbox" class="rowBox" name="selectCurrentRow" id="selectCurrentRow">
                                </td>
                                <td><span>Mahadev </span></td>
                                <td><span>92</span></td>
                                <td><span>Shiva</span></td>
                                <td><span>Some</span></td>
                                <td><span>Salsette</span></td>
                                <td><span >5/25/2023</span></td>
                                <td>Dummy Remark</td>
                                <td><a style="color:white;"
                                        class="btn btn-success btn-sm btn-rounded editbtn" title="Edit"><i
                                            class="mdi mdi-pencil"></i></a> <a 
                                        class="btn btn-rounded btn-secondary btn-sm viewBtn" style="color:white;"><i
                                            class="mdi mdi-eye"></i></a> <a 
                                        class="btn btn-rounded btn-danger btn-sm deleteBtn" style="color:white;"><i
                                            class="mdi mdi-delete"></i></a></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td><input type="checkbox" class="rowBox" name="selectCurrentRow" id="selectCurrentRow">
                                </td>
                                <td><span>Mahadev </span></td>
                                <td><span>92</span></td>
                                <td><span>Shiva</span></td>
                                <td><span>Some</span></td>
                                <td><span>Salsette</span></td>
                                <td><span >5/25/2023</span></td>
                                <td>Dummy Remark</td>
                                <td><a style="color:white;"
                                        class="btn btn-success btn-sm btn-rounded editbtn" title="Edit"><i
                                            class="mdi mdi-pencil"></i></a> <a 
                                        class="btn btn-rounded btn-secondary btn-sm viewBtn" style="color:white;"><i
                                            class="mdi mdi-eye"></i></a> <a 
                                        class="btn btn-rounded btn-danger btn-sm deleteBtn" style="color:white;"><i
                                            class="mdi mdi-delete"></i></a></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td><input type="checkbox" class="rowBox" name="selectCurrentRow" id="selectCurrentRow">
                                </td>
                                <td><span>Mahadev </span></td>
                                <td><span>92</span></td>
                                <td><span>Shiva</span></td>
                                <td><span>Some</span></td>
                                <td><span>Salsette</span></td>
                                <td><span >5/25/2023</span></td>
                                <td>Dummy Remark</td>
                                <td><a style="color:white;"
                                        class="btn btn-success btn-sm btn-rounded editbtn" title="Edit"><i
                                            class="mdi mdi-pencil"></i></a> <a 
                                        class="btn btn-rounded btn-secondary btn-sm viewBtn" style="color:white;"><i
                                            class="mdi mdi-eye"></i></a> <a 
                                        class="btn btn-rounded btn-danger btn-sm deleteBtn" style="color:white;"><i
                                            class="mdi mdi-delete"></i></a></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td><input type="checkbox" class="rowBox" name="selectCurrentRow" id="selectCurrentRow">
                                </td>
                                <td><span>Mahadev </span></td>
                                <td><span>92</span></td>
                                <td><span>Shiva</span></td>
                                <td><span>Some</span></td>
                                <td><span>Salsette</span></td>
                                <td><span >5/25/2023</span></td>
                                <td>Dummy Remark</td>
                                <td><a style="color:white;"
                                        class="btn btn-success btn-sm btn-rounded editbtn" title="Edit"><i
                                            class="mdi mdi-pencil"></i></a> <a 
                                        class="btn btn-rounded btn-secondary btn-sm viewBtn" style="color:white;"><i
                                            class="mdi mdi-eye"></i></a> <a 
                                        class="btn btn-rounded btn-danger btn-sm deleteBtn" style="color:white;"><i
                                            class="mdi mdi-delete"></i></a></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td><input type="checkbox" class="rowBox" name="selectCurrentRow" id="selectCurrentRow">
                                </td>
                                <td><span>Mahadev </span></td>
                                <td><span>92</span></td>
                                <td><span>Shiva</span></td>
                                <td><span>Some</span></td>
                                <td><span>Salsette</span></td>
                                <td><span >5/25/2023</span></td>
                                <td>Dummy Remark</td>
                                <td><a style="color:white;"
                                        class="btn btn-success btn-sm btn-rounded editbtn" title="Edit"><i
                                            class="mdi mdi-pencil"></i></a> <a 
                                        class="btn btn-rounded btn-secondary btn-sm viewBtn" style="color:white;"><i
                                            class="mdi mdi-eye"></i></a> <a 
                                        class="btn btn-rounded btn-danger btn-sm deleteBtn" style="color:white;"><i
                                            class="mdi mdi-delete"></i></a></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td><input type="checkbox" class="rowBox" name="selectCurrentRow" id="selectCurrentRow">
                                </td>
                                <td><span>Mahadev </span></td>
                                <td><span>92</span></td>
                                <td><span>Shiva</span></td>
                                <td><span>Some</span></td>
                                <td><span>Salsette</span></td>
                                <td><span >5/25/2023</span></td>
                                <td>Dummy Remark</td>
                                <td><a style="color:white;"
                                        class="btn btn-success btn-sm btn-rounded editbtn" title="Edit"><i
                                            class="mdi mdi-pencil"></i></a> <a 
                                        class="btn btn-rounded btn-secondary btn-sm viewBtn" style="color:white;"><i
                                            class="mdi mdi-eye"></i></a> <a 
                                        class="btn btn-rounded btn-danger btn-sm deleteBtn" style="color:white;"><i
                                            class="mdi mdi-delete"></i></a></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td><input type="checkbox" class="rowBox" name="selectCurrentRow" id="selectCurrentRow">
                                </td>
                                <td><span>Mahadev </span></td>
                                <td><span>92</span></td>
                                <td><span>Shiva</span></td>
                                <td><span>Some</span></td>
                                <td><span>Salsette</span></td>
                                <td><span >5/25/2023</span></td>
                                <td>Dummy Remark</td>
                                <td><a style="color:white;"
                                        class="btn btn-success btn-sm btn-rounded editbtn" title="Edit"><i
                                            class="mdi mdi-pencil"></i></a> <a 
                                        class="btn btn-rounded btn-secondary btn-sm viewBtn" style="color:white;"><i
                                            class="mdi mdi-eye"></i></a> <a 
                                        class="btn btn-rounded btn-danger btn-sm deleteBtn" style="color:white;"><i
                                            class="mdi mdi-delete"></i></a></td>
                            </tr>
                            
                        </tbody>

                    </table>
                </table>
            </div>
        </main>
        <!-- page-content" -->
    </div>
    <!-- page-wrapper -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    

    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.13.4/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.1/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.1/js/buttons.flash.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jszip/3.1.3/jszip.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.32/pdfmake.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.32/vfs_fonts.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.1/js/buttons.html5.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.1/js/buttons.print.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/fixedheader/3.3.2/js/dataTables.fixedHeader.js"></script>
    
</body>
```

CSS & JS in fiddle.

When I was toggling the sidebar then I called the function fixedHeader.adjust(), but it's not working for the first time and then started working wrongly.

Comment: You should update your version of Bootstrap. 4.0.0 is extremely old. Use 4.6.x instead.

Comment: FYI, `$(document).ready(function() {}` and `jQuery(function($)` do essentially the same thing. You can just use the one around everything.

Comment: My comments were not intended to be solutions. I spent some time with your issue last week but couldn't find anything. You may need to simplify the situation to troubleshoot. See if you can get `adjust()` to work in isolation.